# Python update query in mariadb

Tags: python, database, mariadb

I am trying to update my mariadb table via python code .While compile the query nothing happen in my database. please check below code and let me know where i made mistake in update function

```
import mariadb

connection= mariadb.connect(user="user1", database="db1", host="ippp" ,password="pass")

cursor= connection.cursor()

cursor.execute("UPDATE product_options_combinations SET quantity=5944 WHERE item_code ='31628'")


cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello here I have a clean code example for you. How to update it.

```
import pymysql
  
# Create a connection object
# IP address of the MySQL database server
Host = "localhost"  
  
# User name of the database server
User = "user"       
  
# Password for the database user
Password = ""           
  
database = "GFG"
  
conn  = pymysql.connect(host=Host, user=User, password=Password, database)
  
# Create a cursor object
cur  = conn.cursor()
  
  
query = f"UPDATE PRODUCT SET price = 1400 WHERE PRODUCT_TYPE = 'broadband'"
  
cur.execute(query)
  
#To commit the changes
conn.commit() 
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the connection is working properly?
Have you tried to implement a try and catch routine to print mariadb errors?

Something like this:

```
# Connect to MariaDB Platform
import mariadb
try:
    conn = mariadb.connect(
        user="user",
        password="password",
        host="xx.xx.xx.xx",
        port=3306,
        database="db_name"

    )
except mariadb.Error as e:
    print(f"Error connecting to MariaDB Platform: {e}")
    sys.exit(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `connection.commit()` to your code, but I recommend you use a parametrized SQL preferably with a list of tuples,*more of which might be added if needed*, along with `cursor.executemany()` as being more performant for DML statements such as

```py
import mariadb

connection= mariadb.connect(user="user1",
                            password="pass",
                            host="ippp",
                            port=3306,
                            database="db1")
cursor= connection.cursor()

dml="""
    UPDATE product_options_combinations
       SET quantity=%s
     WHERE item_code =%s
    """
val=[
    (5944,'31628')
    ]
cursor.executemany(dml,val)

connection.commit()
cursor.close()    
connection.close()
```