# Python update query in bitnami mariadb

Tags: python, mariadb, bitnami

post : [Python update query in mariadb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69041475/python-update-query-in-mariadb)

I read the above, but it didn't help. maybe due to the different path of mariadb from bitnami mariadb

mysql.sock path : /opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock

bitnami mariadb path : /opt/bitnami/mariadb/bin/mysql

access to mariadb :  mysql -u user -p -S /opt/bitnami/mariadb/tmp/mysql.sock

mysql-connector - installed
mysql-connector-python - installed

In this situation, how can I update the query in python?

```
import mariadb
connection= mariadb.connect(user="user1",
                        password="pass",
                        host="ippp",
                        port=3306,
                        database="db1")
cursor= connection.cursor()

dml="""
    UPDATE product_options_combinations
    SET quantity=%s
    WHERE item_code =%s
    """
val=[
    (5944,'31628')
    ]
cursor.executemany(dml,val)

connection.commit()
cursor.close()    
connection.close()
```

this is an error message

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "kkk.py", line 3, in 
connection = mariadb.connect(
AttributeError: module 'mariadb' has no attribute 'connect'

Comment: What are you doing? Show the code you are doing and the error by editing the question. The layout internal to the container shouldn't make a difference to the python code.

Comment: Databases like mariadb / mysql work as service, there you never need any path usually

Comment: Remove mysql-connector and mysql-connector-python, and install the [mariadb](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/how-to-connect-python-programs-to-mariadb/) python connector.

Comment: Are you running kkk.py from a directory which has a subdirectory mariadb?

Comment: got a new error like this :  python3 kkk.py
Error connecting to MariaDB Platform: Can't connect to local server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'

Comment: This issue has been resolved. Thank you for your comments.